# Do you know any other adverb like this?

Tags: adverbs

> **Be assured**, you are in numerous company...

My professor already has said to me that **BE ASSURED** is an adverb here.

Do you know any other example like that in such situation?

Comment: Your professor has an unusual definition of adverb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of your [previous thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19483/which-part-of-speech-is-be-assured/19925#19925), it was already discussed. So please be specific as to what more you want to know about it? Or, what is in your way of understanding it?

As for the statement of your English teacher that "Be assured" is an adverb in that sentence, I really have no idea how he can say so. Anyways, it's already said that "be assured" in this sentence doesn't have any parts of speech, and isn't possible.

Well, if you want to know more, I ask you to please go back to that thread, and read the replies. Or if you have any more confusion, please ask specifically.

Comment: It was just a guess. With proper context "numerous" might mean something meaningful. So I will remove my guessing part from my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Nonetheless, would you tell me what please ask specifically means?

Comment: @nima_persian When you ask something on a particular thread try to make it clear, so that you don't have to ask anyone again. You can figure it out on your own. Isn't it a good thing? Though there is no harm in asking again and again. By "ask specifically" I meant that describe the exact one what is bothering you in understanding the problem, instead of asking the same question again. You see there is no actual difference between your question you asked today and the one you asked earlier. Same question, same answer, and your confusion still persists.